# Cannot build the "Hello world" cumulocity example with Maven

Tags: maven, cumulocity

I am walking through the Cumulocity IoT Guides and I decided to run the "Hello World" example, which can be found here:
http://cumulocity.com/guides/device-sdk/java#hello-world-basic

I went through all the steps and a problem occurred at the last step - the execution of the example.
I got this error from maven:

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=c8y.example.App". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

Currently the environment is :
jdk1.7.0_80

maven3.1.1 (as in the example)

Comment: Please show us the Maven call, you've made.

Comment: Hi 

It was just the same as the described in the example:
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="c8y.example.App"

And this call was made from the newly created "hello-agent" directory:

C:\Users\xxxxxx\hello-agent> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="c8y.example.App"

Comment: Ah ok, did not get the redirection to the second Maven call, thanks.

Comment: Please show us how the pom.xml file looks like. And why are you using explicitly maven to run it?

Comment: Hello, i solved the problem with adding quotation marks. mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="c8y.example.App". Also i use explicitly maven just because i am trying to make this example run and the example is shown with maven usage.